# jedis or redis trouble with encoding ISO-8859-5

Tags: java, encoding, redis, jedis

I test redis and jedis API for encoding ISO-8859-5:

```
        String S = new String("Привет мир".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-5");
    redis.lpush("test", S);
    System.out.println(redis.lpop("test"));
```

In result, I have: а�б�аИаВаЕб� аМаИб�

Then I try to use SafeEncoder:

```
        String S = new String("Привет мир".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-5");
    redis.lpush("test", S);
    byte[] Result = SafeEncoder.encode(redis.lpop("test"));
    System.out.println(new String(Result));
```

Result: аАТаБТаАааАааАааБТ аАааАааБТ

What I do wrong? Is it me or redis, or jedis?

Comment: Test it on Linux Debian, Redis v. 2.2.12

Comment: Any success on make it work?

Comment: `String S = new String("Привет мир".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-5");` This code is totally incorrect. First you convert bytes to your default encoding (it depends on platform which one it is) and then you convert those bytes to ISO-8859-5. The result is some garbage that you are trying to push to Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the binary form directly

```
byte[] b = "Привет мир".getBytes();
redis.lpush(SafeEncoder.encode("test"), b);
System.out.println(redis.lpop("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try convert information to UTF-8.
by the way, if you have problems with cyrrilic encoding , this site may help you ( [2cyr.com](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) )

Comment: please provider a better example (ideally using code) of what you mean